# What is natural join doing in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Why am I not getting the rows having salesman_id as 5002,5003 and 5007 in my output after executing the natural join query ?[image]

Comment: You should never use `NATURAL JOIN`. It is dangerous, because by merely adding one column later you can unintentionally break existing queries. This type of join really invites future problems. They must have been out of their minds when they invented it.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Explain what you expected & why, with justification referencing authoritative documentation. Otherwise you're just asking for yet another presentation with a bespoke tutorial with no info on your misconceptions. [mre]

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They are obscure, error prone, and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 4):

Natural Join looks for columns that have the same name, then performs an INNER JOIN using those columns. In your example, this is 'salesman_id' AND 'city'.

The rows that are not in the output do not share a city with any rows in the other table.

I am not sure exactly what the output you want is, but it seems like you want to join the customer to the salesman id, which you can do like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    customer as c
INNER JOIN 
    salesman as s 
ON c.salesman_id = s.salesman_id;
```

Comment: Just a note. Natural joins can also perform outer joins (left, right, full). In any case, it's better to avoid them.

Answer (score 3):

Natural join is just an inner join that matches **all** columns in both tables with a common name. Both tables have a `salesman_id` column, which you did intend to use, and a `city` column, which you probably did *not* intend to use.

Personally, I pretty much never use natural join. Instead I always write out the inner join equivalent, because you never know when someone will need to add a column to a table that suddenly brings a new field into the join for a query you had forgotten about, and break a working application.